# How to count found markers rajawali vuforia?

Tags: marker, vuforia, rajawali

I am trying to get the number of found markers on rajawali vuforia.

while we have the methods:

1- `protected void foundFrameMarker(final int markerId, Vector3 position,Quaternion orientation) {} // this method is called when found any marker until the marker disappeared`

2- `public void noFrameMarkersFound() {} // this method is called when no markers appeared or found`

How to use these methods to get count of found markers? Or is there another way to get the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foundFrameMarker` is called for each currently detected marker in a loop, every frame. In order to count found markers, you should add an int variable to your renderer for counting them. Reset it at the beginning of the render loop (`onRenderFrame`), and increment it inside `foundFrameMarker`:

```
public void onRenderFrame(GL10 gl) {
   ... 
   mMarkerCount = 0;
   ...
 }

 protected void foundFrameMarker(int markerId, Vector3 position, Quaternion orientation) {
   mMarkerCount++;
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@yakobom answer's solved the problem but it repeats counting every frame so I added some code:
I initialized another int to get the `max` count that `mMarkerCount` reachs, on the activity class in the `onCreate(...)` I added a timer that refresh every second to set it into a TextFeild and to reset the max.

in the Activity class in the onCreate:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            te.setText(mRenderer.max+"");
                            mRenderer.max=0;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

at the Renderer class:

```
protected void foundFrameMarker(int markerId, Vector3 position,
        Quaternion orientation) {

    ...

    mMarkerCount++;

    if (mMarkerCount > max)
        max = mMarkerCount;

    ...

}
```

Comment: A second may be good, or not. Vuforia updates the exact state of detected markers / targets every frame, so the accurate way to do it is every frame - I agree that if you have some performance problems, which is not likely due to this, you can start compromising...